# how to transform an enum/literal

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

Hi kind of new to typescript and been trying to transform an enum/literal to another enum/literal using a function.

For example, a capitalize function that takes a string and returns the same string with the first letter as a capital. (i.e map `type name = "ryuma"` to `"Ryuma"`)

```
function capitalize<T>(str:T & string){
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
}

const myName = 'ryuma' as const
const result = capitalize(myName)
```

Here, result gets a type of string, but I want it to have a type of "Ryuma". Is there a way to:

- ensure the function preserves the information about the literal and thus returns the type "Ryuma"
- or to transform the type of the input `str: T & string` such that it returns the capitalized version of the input.

[Here is a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-bgkces?file=/src/index.ts) which contains the type hints for the return value of capitalize.

I tried testing a bunch of variations but couldn't get something to preserve the information, any help would be greatly appreciated ty :D

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKO9KW) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes that's it ty so much, sorry if its a noob question T~T.

Comment: is there a way to define custom functions like Capitalize<T> , so that i could take for example `"MyName" -> "myName"`

Comment: Is that a followup question?  TS has some [built-in intrinsic string manipulation utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) that you can't easily re-implement.  It *might* be possible to implement a custom string manipulation type using character-by-character transformations, but you'd have to describe it exactly.  What you describe just looks like `Uncapitalize<T>` which is already built in.

Comment: just found custom utility types, seems to be the way to go thanks again so much !

Comment: I can write up an answer to your question as asked, and if you still have follow-up questions you should ask them as separate posts.

Comment: Would be helpful for sure, think I got the gist but will upvote once I have enough rep!

Comment: @jcalz's solution is the best possible solution to your specific problem, and it should be an answer. But just remember that typescript is just a preprocessor designed to help us avoid errors. Nothing of typescript remains in the code the users run, and as such there are very few cases where you want to compute actual values in the type system

Comment: yup ik, theres an orm called prisma and it generates a big object which uncapitalizes model names, im trying to make a  cms built ontop of it so was accepting model names as capitals (for use in other places),  but needed to uncapitalize them while maintaining type information for the object prisma generates. But was just curious in the genreal case ty :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has some built-in [intrinsic string manipulation utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) including [the `Capitalize<T>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) which turns a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) input into a capitalized version where the first character is uppercased and the rest of the string literal is unchanged.

This is exactly what your `capitalize()` function does, so it makes sense for you to give it a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature `<T extends string>(str: T) => Capitalize<T>` (where you [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to `string`, which is preferable to having `T` unconstrained and making `str` of type `T & string`).

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't understand what [the `charAt()`,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) [the `toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), or [the `slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) string methods or the [string concatenation operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) actually do to string literal types.  It knows that they produce `string`s in general, but it doesn't know that, for example, `"foo".toUpperCase()` has literal type `"FOO"` specifically.  That means the compiler can't easily *verify* that `capitalize(str)` returns `Capitalize<typeof str>`.

So, for now at least, you'd have to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that you are returning a value of the right type, via  `return (...) as Capitalize<T>`.  Like this:

```
function capitalize<T extends string>(str: T){
  return (str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)) as Capitalize<T>;
}
```

Now we can test it:

```
const myName = 'ryuma' as const
const result = capitalize(myName);
// const result: "Ryuma"
```

Looks good. The compiler knows that `result` is of literal type `"Ryuma"`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgBxlFAbGAvAUwB4AVRAgDygLABMBnReqAJxjAHMA+ACmZYBciEgEoA3gFgAUIkQsCUECyR9WAOggALFCwCCUHgAYRaqHACqaNARYBhFPQI8RiANRN19XBCcBGES4OiPYYWLiEpFwA3NIAvtLSEAjMiAC2AJ4AciipBIgAvIgA5CzpIKkoRYhBSWDMiclQcgT0INhNhaihOPhOGdm5IjFSAPQjyI3Nre1CAEQASmUVswlSQA)

Note: you could go through a lot of effort, as shown in [this Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgBxlFAbGAvAUwB4AVRAgDygLABMBnReqAJxjAHMA+ACmZYBciEgEpEAbwCwAKERzELAlBAskfVgDoIACxQsAglB4AGERqhwAqmjQEWAYRT0CPMxASoj-DfVwQXAIwiwQDcMgC+Mu5gzIgAtgCeAHIocQSIALyIAOQsCSBxKNmITsgIzFHlUAoE9CDY1VmoGFi4hDyJKWkiYdIA9H1lMdWKdQ1CAEQASvmFEzIyUAm2iADKrCRw+iwsRKvkVDQMTKzsHAA0iPoH1HSM-GcA2gC6mYgvXG-7lLfHAAYAEnE7GAdkQADFwkCQWCpuE-ogAPwyeRrDZbHZEKaXR4aPH6S7g56fIS4-GXPEaCYTF7PXpLFb2XQGKB7G5He6nTiXJLsu6IMAFABGdk+WXWLE2212qy4jySdMWy3SACk4OxSHzjg9OC9LgARLWcticN7Uy7XH4ck4mjhmiZilHyMhW-mPGEsCFGm1nCl4j2IKbenUcWlOuSIxBqjXYxD6y6A8T6KFJ73UpGIdNCfUpyF-ElXenKtZoXBQaUoBKa13HFBgBJ6xC8muMQVxEUsC3eusN15ZD6ZcNN736R7ZbA0DhQbTZV6Rx4E4SvIQuw5ugPgv0aANTOclssVquxpI4ymLolcIekxckRXSBnpVZ+AiH6tr2v1xvgz0tgXCuyXJs3pth2jqyPIqylpgr6QQeOyVqQgFwHKxjPISLBygEzxKisT4wP4bK-iG6HAf+nbCHApHtqKg7gXI0ZgHsz4wei0p7Fw6FIVwl7SOw1AsMAKD+GitoSEOOh6IYRDNu+rZkZc3yyT6nC8NOMD0EIqyXGAQhJCIQhMpJrJaU2XC9KiFjWLYDhOMQim-MaZyqdo6mafpiBWXYqDOOx5nyNEniEUpxHCMGXLcDwakaWslxwNOdgru5iarCmJDwn5ci+PhdlhbaJG-iBAEUVRHZfGOE6cNOs7Oa5MWIMALBwHEQjfpcFiIiucDuXhBEma1FE8ZE0hAA), to teach the compiler how to figure out what `charAt()`, `toUpperCase()`, `concat()`m and `slice()` do at the string literal type level, but it's very complicated and fragile and probably scales poorly.  Unless you have some compelling reason not to, I'd stick with the type assertion `as Capitalize<T>`.